# How to add Content-Security-Policy header in rest api-response spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, angular-fullstack

I tried with the below code

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      // ...
      .headers()
        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self'"))
      // ...
  }
}
```

when I am hitting any endpoint from swagger in response I am getting the X-Content-Security header

the same when I am testing with my local UI getting the below error kindly help. http://localhost:4200 . Has been blocked by CORS policy: response to pre flight request does not pass access control check.

Comment: When you hit from UI, are you hitting from one URL to another. Then it won't be allowed unless you specify cross origin allowed.

Comment: You can refer more from https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/